# iOS app crashes when updated but not when loaded new

Tags: ios

I am adding an in-app purchase option to my existing app and when I test it on the simulator, it works fine. When I test it on my iOS device through Xcode, it crashes when I get to the in-app purchase code.

The weird thing about it is that if I delete the existing app from my device and then test it, it works flawlessly. This makes me think that there isn't anything wrong with the code but I'm stumped as to what else it could be.

Has anyone else run into anything similar?

Comment: Always delete your apps before testing a new version. There are always weird crashes and glitches if you don't.

Comment: so it doesn't represent what will happen when users load my update?

Comment: Nope. It's just extra data that corrupts the new version. It has nothing to do with a fresh build.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the data model has changed. When you update your app instead of installing new, the core data or database does not get replaced, so you are using the new code with old data model. Delete and re-install is the correct solution although some don't understand the reason.